# How to make OAuth flow secure using state parameter

Tags: node.js, security, authentication, oauth, shopify

Background: The frontend is an Airtable app (basically an iframe runing in the Airtable UI). The backend is a Node server with a Postgres database, running on Heroku. I'm using Firebase for authentication. I'm trying to add an OAuth integration with Shopify.

- OAuth requires me to use the `state` parameter to prevent CSRF attacks, which the backend should use to check the session that initiated the request is the same as the session that handles the redirect.
- The OAuth flow starts in my Airtable app. It calls `window.open('https://{shop}.myshopify.com/admin/oauth/authorize?client_id={api_key}&scope={scopes}&redirect_uri={redirect_uri}&state={nonce}&grant_options[]={access_mode}')`, which opens a new tab that takes the user through a Shopify OAuth flow.
- The `redirect_uri` is outside my app (it's a backend URL). Because this is happening in a new tab, it's a different session to the one that started the flow, so there's not way to check the `state` parameter is from the same session.

**Current solution**

I'm setting `state` to the `accountId` of the user, so when Shopify redirects to the `redirect_uri`, the backend know which user the authorization code is for. This works, but it does not fulfil the requirement of validatng the sessions are the same and preventing CSRF attacks.

**Potential solution**

When the user initiates a request, send the first to a backend URL from the Airtable app, create a session (e.g. with `express-session`), then redirect them to Shopify with this session as the `state` parameter. This can then be used after the redirect, by checking the session is the same as the one that initiated the request.

This solutions appears to fulfil the OAuth `state` requirement. However, when the user opens the initial link from the Airtable app to the backend would need to include something for the backend to identify them (e.g. `accountId`, a JWT).

If an attacker shared one of these links with their own account details, e.g. in a phishing email, and a user went through the OAuth flow, the user would link their Shopify account to the attackers account in my service. Is there any way to avoid this?